# Python binary-data ascii error when encoding in multipart

Tags: python, http-post, multipartform-data

I'm using this [cookbook recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146306/) to encode images in a multipart form data to upload to Twitter.

When I run the code to pack the image in a django shell everything runs fine (even the print statements that I used to debug the post body with binary data) but when I try to run the same script from a django Command or a much simpler pure-python script I keep getting this error:

```
body = '\r\n'.join(body)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So, why is this happening only when I run a script and not from the shell/CLI?

Thanks for everyone who can enlighten me into this :)

Comment: Do you just call the join method ? Or does the error occur if you try to print the result ?

Comment: The error occurs when I call the join method, even if I remove the print statements it still will occur

Comment: Have you read all the comments on that recipe?? A brief skim through indicates (1) it uses a deprecated something or other (2) somebody had a decode error and somebody else suggested a fix.

Comment: Yeap, I've read it and tried the fix, I'm posting the answer from what I find was the error, thanks for all the help :)

Comment: @piva: You are posting the answer *where*?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290601/unicodedecodeerror-when-using-socket-gethostname-result) question.
Does the answer provided there help you?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it was related to the results of my query.
They were returned in unicode and I used that value to create the path to my image, like:

```
image_path = "/my/path/%s.jpg" % model.name
```

model.name was something like u'model1' I printed out these values and removed the u' notation (by the old method of replacing :P) from the strings all worked fine.

What left me very frustrated is that the error pointed to '\r\n'.join and never to something related to the name of my file.

Comment: """model.name was something like u'model1' I printed out these values and removed the u' notation (by the old method of replacing :P) from the strings all worked fine.""" ... that's a bit like cutting your toenails with the electric chainsaw while you're sitting in the bath.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but it was just a debugging test and not the actual method that I used to run the script